# Is there a parameter similar "'name__like" for WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the [Get Terms();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) WordPress function, you can get terms using the "name__like" parameter to only get terms that start with whatever characters you enter.

I need to use a new WP_Query, and I can't find a similar parameter:

```
$my_qry = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'title', 'order' => 'DESC',  'post_status' => 'publish' ) );
```

This gives me an array of all the posts published. How can I filter the found posts to only show posts that start with certain words/characters (by post title)?

Comment: You can do it on meta data (custom fields) like `$query = new WP_Query(array('meta_key' => 'color', 'meta_value' => 'blue', 'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'));` ... See http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters but I can't see anything for post title...

Comment: I don't use/have custom fields set, so I can't use that. I was hoping for a name__like type parameter or a way to get the same behaviour.